# The type or namespace name 'UWP' does not exist in the namespace 'PdfSharp.Xamarin.Forms'

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, pdf-generation, pdfsharp

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms app with PDF features. I am taking my first shot at using **PdfSharp** (PdfSharp.Xamarin.Forms forked from PdfSharpCore) but finding it's not entirely developer-friendly. I'm trying to use PDFManager and **PDFManager.GeneratePDFFromView** and was able to do so successfully in my Android project, but it's not working in UWP. The [Git page](https://github.com/akgulebubekir/PDFSharp.Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/PdfSharp.Xamarin.Sample/PdfSharp.Xamarin.Sample.UWP/App.xaml.cs) says to init in the UWP App.xaml.cs like this:

```
PdfSharp.Xamarin.Forms.UWP.Platform.Init();
```

But when I try this I get the error "The type or namespace name 'UWP' does not exist in the namespace 'PdfSharp.Xamarin.Forms'". Again, I had no problems initializing in Android, but .UWP is not recognized for UWP. I would open this as an issue on GitHub but the option doesn't seem to be there for this repository.

Comment: I have the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

You need to either find PdfSharp.Xamarin.Forms.UWP.dll from the source website directly or download the sample code from that website and build it.  Either way this .dll is the file you are looking for. Once you have a copy of this file, use Project>Reference 'Add Reference' to add this .dll to your UWP project. You should find that PdfSharp.Xamarin.Forms.UWP.Platform.Init() is now accepted.

..But of course there is NO guarantee that PdfSharp.Xamarin.Forms will WORK even if you DO successfully add the library ...